# Qt/PyQt: How do I pass extra arguments when painting a widget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, paint

I need to call several `QWidget.update(rectangle)` on the same widget, each time in a different or same rectangle. But the paint method needs more information, i.e. what to *do* in that rectangle. Highlight? Cursor? Fill? etc. So how do I pass the `paintEvent()` this extra information? [I am using PyQt, but an answer in Qt is fine also.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I've worked out for python:

Create several 'paint' methods, for example `paintAction1(self, event)`, `paintAction2(self, event)`.
Then, whenever you need a specific one, reassign the default `paintEvent` method to the correct one, for example `self.paintEvent = self.paintAction1`, etc. You can event create a default 'paint' method, and have each unusual one reassign 'self.paintEvent' back to the default one upon completion.